# Eigenvalue interpretation with direction field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am running into some trouble with respect to some direction field plots of different eigenvalues.

I am working with a system given as follows:

$$ \overrightarrow{y'} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -5 \\ 1 & a  \end{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{y} $$

where a is some constant that relates to some constant. I am choosing different values of a to see the direction plot but the thing is, it appears as if all my direction field looks quite like a spiral, especially for my case of the repeated eigenvalues.

Anyways, having solved for the different cases, I chose values of $a$ which yielded the respective eigenvalues as follows: $$ a = 4.4721, \lambda_1=2.2361; \lambda_2 = 2.2361 $$

$$ a = 3; \lambda_1 = 1.5 + 1.66i; \lambda_2 = 1.5-1.66i$$

$$ a = 7; \lambda_1 = 0.8074; \lambda_2 = 6.1926$$

[image]

[image]

I am a bit confused as to why the two plots look awfully similar. I have, however, set the same values of solution as given by the curves on the plots for each, but I don't think that should affect my direction field. How would one distinguish the difference between plots of direction field for repeated eigenvalues and complex eigenvalues?

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I realized that I couldn't post the 3rd link to the real eigenvalues' figure but I am able to more or less distinguish a slight difference for that one, but it is the repeated and complex that has gotten me quite confused.

Comment: Yes that is what I did to solve for the different cases to distinguish the between the repeated eigenvalues, and complex eigenvalues. Do you mean that I should try out other eigenvalues to see the difference in terms of the interaction between the eigenvectors ?

Comment: If we change $a$ from $-8,8$ in steps of $1$, we get the eigenvalues: $(-7.31662,-0.683375),(-6.19258,-0.807418),(-5.,-1.),(-3.61803,-1.38197),(-2.-1. I,-2.+1. I),(-1.5-1.65831 I,-1.5+1.65831 I),(-1.-2. I,-1.+2. I),(-0.5-2.17945 I,-0.5+2.17945 I),(0. -2.23607 I,0. +2.23607 I),(0.5 -2.17945 I,0.5 +2.17945 I),(1. -2. I,1. +2. I),(1.5 -1.65831 I,1.5 +1.65831 I),(2. -1. I,2. +1. I),(1.38197,3.61803),(1.,5.),(0.807418,6.19258),(0.683375,7.31662)$. Notice the changes from both positive, both negative. complex? What does this do to the direction fields?

Comment: Hm, I seem to see something, having generated 17 figures, the arrows tend to change shift from pointing inwards to pointing outward for values of $a$ as it increases. It is definetly more noticeable looking at the solutions curve. I was expecting more of a noticeable change between the shift from, say, real eigenvalues to complex eigenvalues to repeated. In this case, the change is very minimal but it is more of a continuous slide show as the values change. Is this the case most of the time, I was hardly able to notice the dominant eigenvector for the repeated eigenvalue case